# Defining enum at runtime to populate UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, enums

I am populating a UITableView using a enum. Now at run time, after I get server data, I need to decide whether to populate the first section or not. So, I need to remove the first enum (MyListSectionType1) entry to have it working.

```
typedef enum {
    MyListSectionType1,
    MyListSectionType2,
    MyListSectionType3,
    MyListSectionType4,
    MyListSectionType5,
    MyListSectionType6,
    MyListSectionType7,

    MyListSectionTypeMax,

} MyListSectionType;
```

I thought of trying with below code but how to define showShow at run time is another issue. I tried defining it in the class where I get the server data but this is not working. Any Clue?

```
typedef enum {
#ifdef showShow
    MyListSectionType1,
#endif
    MyListSectionType2,
    MyListSectionType3,
    MyListSectionType4,
    MyListSectionType5,
    MyListSectionType6,
    MyListSectionType7,

    MyListSectionTypeMax,

} MyListSectionType;
```

Comment: You can't change an `enum` at runtime. In fact, at runtime and `enum` doesn't exist. It all just gets converted to integers at compile time. Why don't you change your question so it covers the problem you are trying to solve instead of asking about one possible solution.

Comment: You can't do it with #ifdef anyway since that is a pre processor directive. Evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in runtime. Also `#ifdef` is a preprocessor directive and it is processed during compilation.
You can use array instead and add and remove items in run-time. So you'll have something like

```
NSMutableArray *arr = @[@"Section 1", @"Section 2", @"Section 3"];
```

If you get response that first section is not needed then you can call

```
[arr removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Only that the first element has index 0 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have worked it out by moving MyListSectionType1 to last in the enum list and then in - `(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` conditionally return MyListSectionTypeMax - 1.